# Wordpress e-commerce display products on page template

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I just started working with wordpress e-commerce and on this page it currently displays pictures of panties but they are from custom fields, i need to grab the actual products and display the thumbnail.
http://dpc.tazsoldev.com/meetdirtypantygirls/miss-creamy/

i want to grab panty products from a categorty and display them at the bottom where they currently show. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking, but it sounds like instead of just pictures of items you want them to be clickable items with data associated with them that can be clicked on more more info, moved around and added to carts and such. Is this the case or am I going about what you asking wrong. Also you might want to fix that enter page. It ask for a username and such, you can click cancel and go straight through, but its still annoying to have in the way.

Comment: yeah i just want to display the products on that page for panties. It's not my site its a company's site i have no clue what they use that for

Comment: i want to query e-commerce products on a page template and display them

Comment: Well the pictures are going to have to go into a database. From there you can attach data to the pictures and then fetch them from the database. They can then be sorted in a number of way, and be displayed with the correct information, added to carts, and other various things. If you are trying to build an e-commerce site from scratch and have never done it I do not recommend it at all, especially on the scale you seem to want to do it. You need a lot of programming no how. I would recommend [ZenCart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) or [Etsy.com](http://www.etsy.com/) for what you want to do.